# PHP preg_match not matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Please could someone explain to me why this regex does not match anything, when it should:

```
preg_match('@<title>([^<].)</title>@',$meta,$match);
```

I'm trying to match everything between the `<title>` and `</title>` tags, bearing in mind that there could be more than one, so the regex must be ungreedy.

Comment: If that's XML you're trying to regex, then don't... Every time you regex html/xml, Alan Turing kills a kitten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must mean `([^<]+)` or `([^<]*)` instead of `([^<].)` as the latter means to match something not `<` and followed by any character

Comment: Actually I meant `*`, but yes that is exactly the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That `.` will just match one character (any character). You'll want to slightly modify the preceding expression (`[^<]`--"don't match an open caret"). To make it match more than one, add a `*`. To make that ungreedy, add a `?`:

```
preg_match('@<title>([^<]*?)</title>@',$meta,$match);
```